# How can I get attribute of a div from WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I have a web page that has

```
<div class="mydiv" style="width: 50%"> div content </div>
```

and I want to get the width value

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');
console.log(elements[0].style.width);
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" style="width: 50%"> div content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the width from the below div,

```
<div class="mydiv" style="width: 50%"> div content </div>
```

Please try,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mydiv" style="width: 50%"> div content </div>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                console.log('page is fully loaded');
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv');
                var st = elements[0].getAttribute('style');
                var width = st.split(':')[1].trim();
                console.log(width);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output in console:

```
page is fully loaded
50%
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var m=document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth;
```

Similarly if you want to know about window width and height you can use

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your js.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".mydiv").style.width);
```